# pandas trim with NA value

Tags: pandas

I have some data frame with the following structure.

```
timestamp             Col_A   Col_B
2021-04-19T16:12:00Z     NA      NA
2021-04-19T16:13:00Z     NA      NA 
2021-04-19T16:14:00Z      1      NA
2021-04-19T16:15:00Z      2      NA
2021-04-19T16:16:00Z      3       1
2021-04-19T16:17:00Z      4       2
2021-04-19T16:18:00Z      5       3
2021-04-19T16:19:00Z      6       4
2021-04-19T16:20:00Z     NA      NA
```

I would like to make a `trim` function where basically it would trim all contiguous NA columns from top and bottom i.e. in this case it would filter the frame as:

```
2021-04-19T16:14:00Z      1      NA
2021-04-19T16:15:00Z      2      NA
2021-04-19T16:16:00Z      3       1
2021-04-19T16:17:00Z      4       2
2021-04-19T16:18:00Z      5       3
2021-04-19T16:19:00Z      6       4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with `cumprod` after `all`

```
s = df.isna().all(1)
out = df[s.cumprod() + s.iloc[::-1].cumprod() == 0]
```

Comment: Had to filter by the columns in the `na` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.first_valid_index.html) and [`last_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.last_valid_index.html)

```py
out = df.loc[df[['Col_A', 'Col_B']].first_valid_index():df[['Col_A', 'Col_B']].last_valid_index(), :]
```

```
print(out)

              timestamp  Col_A  Col_B
2  2021-04-19T16:14:00Z    1.0    NaN
3  2021-04-19T16:15:00Z    2.0    NaN
4  2021-04-19T16:16:00Z    3.0    1.0
5  2021-04-19T16:17:00Z    4.0    2.0
6  2021-04-19T16:18:00Z    5.0    3.0
7  2021-04-19T16:19:00Z    6.0    4.0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can drop the rows that have NA in the defined columns:
`df.dropna(subset=['Col_A', 'Col_B'], how='all')`